# Counting Number of Numbers c#

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers

How do I write a code that allows me to count the number of numbers that i put in a text box. 
For example I have a form , a button and a text box. I type in 1 in the text box; press the button. Type in 3; press the button. Type in 5; press the button. and when I close out my form, a message box shows up saying i have 3 numbers.

code so far for form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnReadings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form2 f2 = new Form2())
        {
            while (f2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Enabled = false;
            }
            this.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

form 2

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: So you have the outline of a form.. that's a start. What have you tried in regards to your actual requirement?

Comment: Like, what i have already done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the form's `Closing` event, like this:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int countOfNumbers = 0;

    foreach(char c in textBox1.Text)
    {
        if(Char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            countOfNumbers += 1;
        }
    }

    // Display a MsgBox asking the user to save changes or abort. 
    MessageBox.Show("Number of numbers in text box is: " + countOfNumbers.ToString());
}
```

Comment: does this work on my second form too

Comment: What is on your second form? The textbox you are typing into or no?

Comment: yes the second form has a button and a textbox

Comment: Then, yes just handle the `Closing` event for `Form2`.